# app crashes only if empty input click

Tags: android

Need help why if I do click: process calculation on Empty string / input then my app always crash. But no issue if there is value:

I've tried many alternative to intercept blank editText, i.e.: if `isEmpty`, `equal("")`, `== null`, including try & catch BUT no success

here is my last code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Button;

public class EngineActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switchButton);

    //Listening to button event
    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Starting a new Intent
        Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EngineSecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(nextScreen);

    }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.engine, menu);
    return true;
}

public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {
    // get the references to the widgets
    EditText antText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.antText);
    EditText degText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.degText);
    EditText spanText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.spanText);
    TextView resultText1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultLabel1);
    TextView resultText2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultLabel2);
    TextView resultText3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultLabel3);
    String ant = antText.getText().toString();
    String deg = degText.getText().toString();
    String span = spanText.getText().toString();

    // make sure we handle the click of the calculator button
    if (view.getId() == R.id.calculateButton) {

     // get the users values from the widget references         
        if (ant.isEmpty() || deg.isEmpty() || span.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Less Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;

        } else {
         float h = Float.parseFloat(ant); 
         float t = Float.parseFloat(deg);
         float b = Float.parseFloat(span);

     // calculate disc value
         float disc1 = calculateDisc1(h, t, b);
         float disc2 = calculateDisc2(h, t);
         float disc3 = calculateDisc3(h, t, b);

     // now set the value in the result text
         resultText1.setText("d1: " + disc1 + " m");
         resultText2.setText("d2: " + disc2 + " m");
         resultText3.setText("d3: " + disc3 + " m");
     }
    }
}

   // the formula to calculate 

   private float calculateDisc1 (float h, float t, float b) {

    return (float) (h / Math.abs(Math.tan((t + b / 2) * Math.PI/180)));
   }

   private float calculateDisc2 (float h, float t) {

    return (float) (h / Math.abs(Math.tan(t * Math.PI/180)));
   }

   private float calculateDisc3 (float h, float t, float b) {

    return (float) (h / Math.abs(Math.tan((t - b / 2) * Math.PI/180)));
   }
```

}

And herewith is crash log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:     at 
    android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (View.java:5385)    at  
    android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6305)    at
    android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:24840)    at
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)    at
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)    at
    android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)    at
    android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6501)    at
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)    at
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)    at
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)

Caused by: 
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:     at
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)    at
    android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (View.java:5380)

Caused by: 
    java.lang.NumberFormatException:     at
    sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString (FloatingDecimal.java:1842)    at
    sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat (FloatingDecimal.java:122)    at 
    java.lang.Float.parseFloat (Float.java:452)    at 
    com.xxx.yyy.EngineActivity.calculateClickHandler (EngineActivity.java:55)
```

herewith is layout xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".EngineActivity" >    

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="638dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/antLabel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/antText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/antText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/antText"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/degLabel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/degText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/antText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/degText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/degText"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/spanLabel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/spanText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/degText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculateButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spanText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spanText"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:onClick="calculateClickHandler"
        android:text="@string/calculateButton" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultLabel1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/calculateButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calculateButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/emptyString1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultLabel2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/resultLabel1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resultLabel1"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/emptyString2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultLabel3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/resultLabel2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resultLabel2"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/emptyString3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/switchButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/calculateButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spanText"
        android:text="@string/switchButton" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="153dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/resultLabel3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/switchButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resultLabel3"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ant" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Use `TextUtils.isEmpty` for checking empty Strings

Comment: Already tried (android.text) TextUtils as well but sorry no success :(

Comment: From where you are invoking calculateClickHandler() ?

Comment: did you try this?
 if(!editText.equal("")){
//goes here when is not empty
}else{
//goes here when is empty
}

Comment: I would recommend you to add attribute **android:inputType="numberDecimal"** for all your edittext those expects value to be entered in float.

Comment: That calculateClickHandler() is main prog to init calculation by click, isn't it

Comment: @INS try below solution, I think it should solve your issue. Please let me know if you still getting crash.

Comment: this android:inputType="numberDecimal" already inputted on <EditText ..> in XML but still crash..

Comment: did you try my answer as well ? we are matching input using regex before parsing.

Comment: Also put one log message to see what values you have in your input fields and share the log message with us.

        `String ant = antText.getText().toString();
        String deg = degText.getText().toString();
        String span = spanText.getText().toString();
  Log.d("TEST", "ant ="+ant+" deg="+deg+" span="+span);`

Comment: @INS did you try adding log ? please share the log message it will help us to find out the cause of issue. I also have modified your method calculateClickHandler.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma thank u for helping but still crash after I added regex util on empty input :(

Comment: @INS can you please share the log. Did you use the code exactly I posted on answer ?

Comment: @KrishnaSharma Sorry for late.. yes i've tried to put add log.d but I received same crash log as above (no difference), or may be I don't know how to get this logcat result ?

Comment: share your complete EngineActivity and layout file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by do Project > Clean before export.. it is due to APK not updated even I've updated EngineActivity.Java syntax, previously when export to APK it still using old Activity.Java that still not filtering empty string (direct to parsefloat without IF statement)

Perhaps it was Eclipse bug when project move to new PC :(

Answer (score 1):

NumberFormatException occurs when the given string is not in specified format.

Float.parseFloat() throws NumberFormatException if the specified argument is not in float format.

For example,

13 -> It is an integer and not of float type.

13.0 -> This is actually in float format.

This also happens if you try to parse for float on a empty string.

Comment: Perhaps.. but if I input integer value i.e. 13 (without decimal) in one or all variables as input in app, the calculation is ok, not crash

Answer (score 0):

Trim values when you read text from the edittext.

```
String ant = antText.getText().toString().trim();
String deg = degText.getText().toString().trim();
String span = spanText.getText().toString().trim();
```

Try checking empty imput using TextUtils.isEmpty() as shown below.

```
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(ant)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Less Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(deg)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Less Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(span)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Less Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        float h = Float.parseFloat(ant);
        float t = Float.parseFloat(deg);
        float b = Float.parseFloat(span);

        // calculate disc value
        float disc1 = calculateDisc1(h, t, b);
        float disc2 = calculateDisc2(h, t);
        float disc3 = calculateDisc3(h, t, b);

        // now set the value in the result text
        resultText1.setText("d1: " + disc1 + " m");
        resultText2.setText("d2: " + disc2 + " m");
        resultText3.setText("d3: " + disc3 + " m");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
float h = Float.valueOf(ant); 
float t = Float.valueOf(deg);
float b = Float.valueOf(span);
```

**OR**

```
float h = Float.valueOf(antText.getText().toString()); 
float t = Float.valueOf(degText.getText().toString());
float b = Float.valueOf(spanText.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some little changes in your code and its working fine for me, whether I insert decimal values or integer value or empty value. Didn't face any crash.

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;

    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.Button;

        public class EngineActivity extends Activity {

            EditText antText, degText, spanText;
            TextView resultText1, resultText2, resultText3;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switchButton);

        antText = findViewById(R.id.antText);
                degText = findViewById(R.id.degText);
                spanText = findViewById(R.id.spanText);
                resultText1 = findViewById(R.id.resultLabel1);
                resultText2 = findViewById(R.id.resultLabel2);
                resultText3 = findViewById(R.id.resultLabel3);
            //Listening to button event
            switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Starting a new Intent
                Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EngineSecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(nextScreen);

            }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.engine, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {
            // get the references to the widgets
            String ant = antText.getText().toString();
            String deg = degText.getText().toString();
            String span = spanText.getText().toString();

            // make sure we handle the click of the calculator button
             if (ant.isEmpty() || deg.isEmpty() || span.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Less Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    float h = Float.parseFloat(ant);
                    float t = Float.parseFloat(deg);
                    float b = Float.parseFloat(span);

                    // calculate disc value
                    float disc1 = calculateDisc1(h, t, b);
                    float disc2 = calculateDisc2(h, t);
                    float disc3 = calculateDisc3(h, t, b);

                    // now set the value in the result text
                    resultText1.setText("d1: " + disc1 + " m");
                    resultText2.setText("d2: " + disc2 + " m");
                    resultText3.setText("d3: " + disc3 + " m");
                }
            }
        }

        // the formula to calculate

        private float calculateDisc1(float h, float t, float b) {

            return (float) (h / Math.abs(Math.tan((t + b / 2) * Math.PI / 180)));
        }

        private float calculateDisc2(float h, float t) {

            return (float) (h / Math.abs(Math.tan(t * Math.PI / 180)));
        }

        private float calculateDisc3(float h, float t, float b) {

            return (float) (h / Math.abs(Math.tan((t - b / 2) * Math.PI / 180)));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to add attribute **android:inputType="numberDecimal"** for all your edittext those expects value to be entered in float.

Also NumberFormatException may come if your edittext is not empty but it has not valid numbers. To avoid that try below

```
String regEx = "[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
boolean validInput = pattern.matcher(ant).matches();
validInput = validInput && pattern.matcher(deg).matches();
validInput = validInput && pattern.matcher(span).matches();
if (!validInput) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Less Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;

} else {
  // parse your inputs here
}
```

Here is the modified **calculateClickHandler** method

```
String regEx = "[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);

    public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {
        // get the references to the widgets
        String ant = antText.getText().toString();
        String deg = degText.getText().toString();
        String span = spanText.getText().toString();
        Log.d("calculateClickHandler", "ant =" + ant + " deg=" + deg + " span=" + span);
        boolean validInput = pattern.matcher(ant).matches();
        validInput = validInput && pattern.matcher(deg).matches();
        validInput = validInput && pattern.matcher(span).matches();
        // make sure we handle the click of the calculator button
         if (!validInput) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Less Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } else {
                float h = Float.parseFloat(ant);
                float t = Float.parseFloat(deg);
                float b = Float.parseFloat(span);

                // calculate disc value
                float disc1 = calculateDisc1(h, t, b);
                float disc2 = calculateDisc2(h, t);
                float disc3 = calculateDisc3(h, t, b);

                // now set the value in the result text
                resultText1.setText("d1: " + disc1 + " m");
                resultText2.setText("d2: " + disc2 + " m");
                resultText3.setText("d3: " + disc3 + " m");
            }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for this.. as in above chat, it still.. FYI I have inputted android:inputType="numberDecimal since beginning

Comment: I am asking for the log, can you please share ?? specially **Log.d("calculateClickHandler", "ant =" + ant + " deg=" + deg + " span=" + span);**

Comment: here u go: 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (View.java:5380)

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
  at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString (FloatingDecimal.java:1842) 
  at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat (FloatingDecimal.java:122) 
  at java.lang.Float.parseFloat (Float.java:452)
  at com.xxx.yyy.EngineActivity.calculateClickHandler (EngineActivity.java:55)  as I told above, do u see any difference

Comment: @INS I am not asking for crash log, I need log for edit text values. Have already added log in my solution **Log.d("calculateClickHandler", "ant =" + ant + " deg=" + deg + " span=" + span);** so you just need to copy from logcat and paste here.

Comment: In studio logcat simply search with keyword **calculateClickHandler** you find that log.

Comment: I am using Eclipse

Comment: @INS no worries, if you can't capture the log then replace line with **Log.d("calculateClickHandler", "ant =" + ant + " deg=" + deg + " span=" + span);** with **resultText1.setText("ant =" + ant + " deg=" + deg + " span=" + span);** Then rerun the app and tell me what it does print in textview

Comment: @INS you are definitely missing something, it's hard us to find out the cause with short piece of activity class. Better if you share your complete EngineActivity and layout file

Comment: @INS just I have tested your code its working fine, if I do not enter any value on all input field and click on calculate button I get toast message 'Less Input". Didn't get any crash. Tell me for what values you are getting crash

Comment: @INS still you getting the crash ?

Comment: yes mine still crash, I guess I done wrong in another syntax instead of numberException due to I got .IllegalStateException & InvocationTargetException related to click. I've tried to insert try&catch on parsefloat but still crash if empty input (unsolved).. perhaps if no input then this clickListener looping or something.. I'm really confused as well :(

Comment: One weird thing I have deleted parsefloat() in all involved line I only left setText printout of ant deg span (curious wanted to see initial value of empty string) by click button but.. why there is still error NumberFormatException: 
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal,readJavaFormatString & java.lang.Float.parseFloat similar as before when I click empty input?

Comment: Solved by do Project > Clean before export.. it is due to APK not updated even I've updated EngineActivity.Java syntax, previously when export to APK it still using old Activity.Java. Perhaps Eclipse bug when project move to new PC

Answer (score 0):

try equalsignorecase(" ")
Hope it helps.